# For a normal distribution, what is the ratio between the standard deviation and the interquartile range?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, ratio

Textbook question:

> For a normal distribution, find the following ratios:
>
> a)$\dfrac{\text{median}}{\text{mean}}$
>
> b $\dfrac{\text{standard deviation}}{\text{interquartile range}}$

Comment: The standard normal distribution has mean 0 so (a) is impossible.  The general normal distribution, with $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\sigma 2\pi}e^{\frac{-(x- \mu)^2}{\sigma^2}}$ is symmetric about its mean so (a) is 1.

Comment: So the median equals the mean? Is that because there are infinite values and so any value can be the median?

Comment: No, it is, as I said, because the normal distribution is SYMMETRIC about the mean.  It is NOT true that "any value can be the median" and has nothing to do with there being "infinite values" (which is not true).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normal distribution the median, mode and mean are all equal. Assuming that they aren't equal to $0$ then this doesn't evaluate to anything.

$$\frac{\text{median}}{\text{mean}} =1 $$

The interquartile range covers the middle 50%, which is $-.67 \sigma $ to  $ .67 \sigma$ 
$$ \frac{\sigma}{ \text{interquartile range }}$$
$$ \frac{\sigma}{ 1.34 \sigma }$$
$$ \frac{1}{1.34} $$

Comment: Sorry, but how do we know that the middle 50% is $−.67σ$ to $.67σ$?

Comment: It was from wikipedia.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interquartile_range ...you have to calculate it with the quartiles which I can add in a moment.